# Multipart, set Content-Type of one part

Tags: java, android, content-type, multipart

I have this code to post data to my server:

```
// HTTP Settings
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://myserver.com/Login");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            // Http Headers
            postRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
            postRequest.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

            // Credentials
            reqEntity.addPart("username", new StringBody(ServerData.username));
            reqEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody(ServerData.password));

            if (m_sigFile.exists()) {
                Bitmap m_sig = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sigFilePath
                        + "m_sig.jpg");
                ByteArrayOutputStream m_bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                m_sig.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, m_bao);

                byte[] m_ba = m_bao.toByteArray();
                String m_ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(m_ba, 0);
                reqEntity.addPart("m_sig.jpg", new StringBody(m_ba1));
            }

            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
```

The code works perfectly, all data is send to the server except for the jpeg file. The server only accepts the file if I set the content type to 'image/jpeg', but only for the image. The username and password has to be in plain text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
            ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(new File(myPath
                    + "image_1.jpg"),
                    "image/jpeg");
            reqEntity.addPart("photo1"), cbFile);
```

Don't forget to check if you file exists!

Answer (score 1):

There is a constructor for `StringBody` that accepts content type:

```
new StringBody(titleString, "application/atom+xml", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```